# Bash Issue Related To Absolute Path Construction From String Variables

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I'm experiencing strange behavior when attempting to construct an absolute path from a number of string variables using bash.  In a bash script, I place a user-specified string into a variable named `project_file`:

```
project_file="DemoCase.iec"
```

From this I create a new variable named `pbase` which stores just the basename for this string as in:

```
pbase="${project_file%.*}"
```

I also make a variable named `pfile` that stores the full path to this `project_file` as in:

```
pfile=$(find $(pwd) -name "${project_file}" -type f 2>/dev/null)
```

Next I parse the contents of this `project_file` in the following manner and place the contents into an array:

```
name=( $(cat ${pfile} | grep -A 2 "MyTargetString" | \
    grep "MyTargetSubString" | awk '{print $2}') )
```

In this example the array is populated with 4 elements (each is a string) which I can confirm by:

```
echo ${#name[@]}
```

However, when I go to print all of the elements of the array as in:

```
echo ${name[@]}
```

only the last element is returned.  I can echo each argument in the array in a for loop as in:

```
for n in ${name[@]}
do
    echo "$n"
done
```

This returns:

```
000
000-CPB
000-NLH-1H
000-NLH-5H
```

as expected.  Now, when I try to use these elements to construct an absolute path as in the following:

```
rdir="${pbase}_${name[3]}"
rfile="$(dirname ${pfile})/${rdir}/${rdir}.run"
```

I end up with something that looks like:

```
.runoCase8_000-NLH-5HoCase8_000-NLH-5H
```

instead of what I was hoping to construct:

```
/home/username/work/shared/DemoCase8_000-NLH-5H/DemoCase8_000-NLH-5H.run
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to what might be my issue in this case?  I've noticed if I construct `rfile` using:

```
rfile="$(dirname ${pfile})/${rdir}"
```

I get:

```
/home/username/work/shared/DemoCase8_000-NLH-5H
```

but if I place anything after `${rdir}` then it appears to wrap around to the beginning overwriting any pre-existing characters.

Comment: IS your file coming from a Windows environment (just guessing when you mention _it appears to wrap around to the beginning overwriting any pre-existing characters_). In that case, `dos2unix` is your friend. By the way, Useless Use of Cat.

Comment: Fixing the carriage returns is the best solution. Alternately, change `echo ${name[@]}` to `printf "%s\n" "${name[@]}"`